# How to install latest Postgresql JDBC jar in SQL Developer 4.0

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, centos6, postgresql-8.4

I am using CentOS and Postgresql as my database.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20754800/2074141) thread SQL Developer can now support Postgresql. So I manage to download the requirement such as [SQL Developer 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and [Postgresql jdbc connector](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).

Is there a step by step procedure how to install the jdbc connector to sql developer? I tried to follow the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/jdbc.html) but with no luck.

I tried to extract/install the jar file using `java -jar postgresql-9.3_1100.jdbc41.jar` the return is `no main manifest attribute in postgresql-9.3_1100.jdbc41.jar`

my java version is: `1.7.0_45`

Comment: It doesn't help that you tried to follow an *incredibly ancient version* of the PostgreSQL documentation. Where exactly are you getting stuck, what's giving you problems? Installing the JDBC driver? Connecting to PostgreSQL? What?

Comment: Installing the JDBC driver..so I can see that Postgresql Tab that they are talking about.

Comment: I think you'll probably have to describe the steps you have taken, and at what point what happened became different to what you thought should happen.

Comment: I believe what I have done is trying to extract/install the jar files using `java -jar postgresql-9.3_1100.jdbc41.jar` the return is `no main manifest attribute in postgresql-9.3_1100.jdbc41.jar`

Comment: my java --version is `1.7.0_45`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just *run* a JDBC driver as if it was an executable JAR.

```
java -jar postgresql-9.3_1100.jdbc41.jar
```

will produce the error:

```
no main manifest attribute in postgresql-9.3_1100.jdbc41.jar
```

because *it has no `main` manifest attribute in the jar*. That's because *you're not supposed to run it*.

Install the JDBC driver, like any other JDBC driver, according to the instructions for your application. See ["Oracle SQL Developer" install JDBC driver](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22Oracle+SQL+Developer%22+install+JDBC+driver).

The above search finds [instructions on installing 3rd party (non-Oracle) JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/thirdparty-095608.html) and ["Configure JDBC in Oracle JDBC driver"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/migration/jdbc-migration-1923524.html). I strongly suggest following those instructions.

In future, please explain step by step what you've done when you're having a problem, where you get stuck, and what you expect to happen instead.

P.s. I've submitted a patch to PgJDBC so that when you try this in future, it'll give you an informative error. See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/112

Comment: You can actually "run" the Postgres JDBC driver: `java -cp postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar org.postgresql.util.PSQLDriverVersion` will display the driver's version. But that too has nothing to do with installing the driver

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Didn't realise that. I've just submitted a patch that adds a mainclass to the driver - it'll print the version from DriverVersion, but also some instructions.

Comment: Now I know..joe!!..joe..In the case of PostgreSQL driver, I was wrong to thought using SQL Developer> Help> Update will check for third party jdbc. The link you provided are so helpful to pass this wall. Thanks.