# PostgreSQL with SQL Developer Issue

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I added my Third Party JDBC drivers for PostgreSQL, the tab shows up.

However, after I fill in the Username/Pwd and Hostname/Port and then select Choose Database - I get:

```
Failure -FATAL: database "user1" does not exist
```

Anyone else having this issue?

The JDBC driver I am using is `postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar`.

Comment: sql developer 4.1 still behaves the same way

Comment: Same here with SQLDevelopper 4.1.0.17. It seems that you must have a same user name and database name to make it work.

Answer (score 69):

If you have a different user and db name, SQLDevelopper 4.1 works with this workarround:

```
username: testuser
password: mypass
Host: 127.0.0.1:1234/testdb?
Port: 1234
```

Don't forget the "?" character.
Then Select Database becomes available and connection works.

Thanks to Piperopoulos who helped me in this post: [Oracle SQL Developer and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592519/oracle-sql-developer-and-postgresql)

Note that schema and tables are not listed by SQLDevelopper.
You can use this request to list them manually:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment- try psql -u user1 in command line to check whether user exist

Comment: I had the DBA create a dummy DB using the same name as the user.  The result was that I was finally able to Choose the DB and connect.  However, the connection does not have any info, like the tables, views, etc.  I am able to run SQL queries and get results, but that is it.  Will keep you posted on our future progress with this issue.