# How to create a Postgresql Connection in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I add a new PostgreSQL server connection in Oracle 12c? 
[option for PostgreSQL is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPaUR.jpg). I have the credentials for PostgreSQL database server but I am unable to add the connection here.

I have added the postgresql-42.1.4.jar to `app\username\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib` path.

**Oracle SQL Developer version - 3.2.20.10**

OS - **Windows 10**

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592519/oracle-sql-developer-and-postgresql . You should download the latest version of SQL developer.

Comment: I have added the third party jar file but the postgresql tab does not show up.