# Create an ER diagram or any DB diagram with tables already existing in postgresql

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do a reverse engineering, I mean instead of from ER diagram get the tables, the opposite way, from the tables and the JPA done, do the db diagram, is it possible?

I'm using PostgreSQL, Postico2 and InteliJ for Jpa/Hibernate

I've found this [`Jeddict`](https://jeddict.github.io/) but I guess it's not what I'm looking for.

**ACLARIMENT : I want from ENTITY to TABLE (Diagram) or from Postico 2 where I see all of the tables to Diagram**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ERD diagram for an existing database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474389/how-to-get-erd-diagram-for-an-existing-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navicat's Data Modeler tool might do what you want. They have a free trial.

https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-data-modeler

Answer (score 2):

Using pgAdmin 4 you can right click on database and choose option Generate ERD.

Answer (score 1):

The one way to do that which I met is to use eclipse plugin called [Hibernate Tools](https://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html) which allows to do it. Please take a look at these references:

[Generating entities from tables](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm)
[Using Hibernate Tools generate entity classes from Tables](https://o7planning.org/en/10125/using-hibernate-tools-generate-entity-classes-from-tables)

Comment: Remember that I want from entity to table, not table to entity

Comment: Ahhh... sorry I thought you want to do it in reverse, I think JPA can generate your database schema after that you can make sql dump of your database.

Comment: How can I do it @Kamil W?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create the tables in an empty schema and then run [DB Visualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) on it.