# Search in DB without direct relation between tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a very large DB. I need to link table1 to table2. Is there such a utility that will display through which tables it is possible to join table1 and table2?

I try used pggraph but did not help

Comment: *"which tables it is possible to join table1 and table2"* - pardon? is the table doesn't have relationship at all (like a foreign key)? are you trying to [create erd from existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474389/generate-the-erd-for-an-existing-database)?

Comment: You can join any two tables (or a table to itself) on any criteria you want. You may want to clarify what you are after.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.