# 1 to 1 relation postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I tried to create a 1-to-1 relationship in PostgreSQL but when i check the ERD it looks like a 1-to-many relationship.

this is my SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE capital (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE country (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100), 
  capital_id INTEGER, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_capital FOREIGN KEY(capital_id) REFERENCES capital(id)
);
```

[image]

Does postgres don't support 1-to-1?

thanks in advance,

Comment: It does, what's the problem?

Comment: Yes Postgres supports 1:1 relationship. The problem is that reverse engineering from your script to the erd there is no difference in a 1:1 and a 1:m.  Further your definition will not prevent multiple multiple capitals for a single country. Enforcing the 1:1 requires a unique constraint on `country.capital_id1`. Then perhaps your reverse engineering tool will detect the 1:1.

Comment: @FrankHeikens PgAdmin shows an one-to-many relation instead of one-to-one.

Comment: @Belayer Adding Unique to capital_id does not fix the issue to tool is use is pgAdmin.

Comment: @FrankHeikens or is it a visual bug in pgAdmin as **Belayer** pointed out?

Comment: I have no idea, I always try to avoid the usage of pgAdmin. There are imho much better tools available, for free and paid.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports 1-to-1, but pgAdmin is not PostgreSQL.

As others have pointed out in the comments, your relationship *is* 1-to-many. You're missing the unique constraint necessary to make it 1-to-1.

pgAdmin may not support 1-to-1 relationships. [The documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/erd_tool.html) does not have a way to make a 1-to-1 relationship.

You can try [other visualization tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474389/how-to-visualize-the-relationships-between-tables-of-a-database-schema) and see if they work better.

---

I find 1-to-1 relationships indicative of a design problem. In your example, the country and its capital are two different entities, but they don't necessarily need two different tables. You can store both entities in one table.

Or we can go the other way. A capital is just a special city. What if you want to store more cities? You need a cities table.

```
create table cities (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null,
  country_id integer not null references countries,
  capital boolean default false
)
```

Now it's 1-to-many.

And to enforce one country, one capital...

```
create unique index one_capital_constraint on cities(country_id) where capital
```

Instead of a 1-to-1 relationship, we have a more useful 1-to-many and a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

@Schwern here is used country and capital just as an example, when running this script:

```
CREATE TABLE capital (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE country (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100), 
  capital_id INTEGER UNIQUE, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_capital FOREIGN KEY(capital_id) REFERENCES capital(id)
);
```

I used pgAdmin and DbBeaver to visualize the database both show it as an one-to-many relationship, it seems like both tools have problem with visualizing one-to-one relationships but if you have the column marked as unique and added the constraint it should be a one-to-one since it can only exists on one record.