# Schemaspy export?

Tags: database, erd, database-diagramming, schemaspy

I'm searching a way to draw a diagram for the complex database of my project. I found [schemaspy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemaspy/) by the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223770/tools-to-generate-database-tables-diagram-with-postgresql), and it fits my need except for one thing: my database is quite complex so that it made a lot of arrow intersections, which make it hard for reading. And the export file is html, so that I can't drag-drop to relocate the tables.

Overall this is a useful tool, but I'm wondering if I can export the diagram to a popular format for other programs to read? Maybe MS Visio, [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn) or another diagram-prototype tool? I have searched on Schemaspy website but found nothing related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is a free command-line tool that diagrams databases. SchemaCrawler is particularly useful when diagramming large and complex schemas, since it can diagram tables based on regular expression searches. In your case, you can consider have not a single database diagram, but multiple ones, one for each business domain in your system.

For example, you could have one diagram for customer related tables, another for accounts and still another for sales. Some tables could be common between them. With SchemaCrawler, you can easily say that you are interested in all tables with a column called CUSTOMER_ID, and parent and child tables down to 2 levels.

SchemaCrawler outputs diagrams in GraphViz DOT format for use in other diagramming tools, as well as any other format supported by GraphViz, such as PDF or PNG.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: Hi Sualeh, do SchemaCrawler has the ability to export the "object relation model"?

Comment: Hoàng, SchemaCrawler only looks at the database, and so cannot infer object relationships.

Comment: thanks for your information. Actually I'm trying to find someway to really drag-n-drop the table. I will give SchemaCrawler a try though