# How to get Odoo 8 database tables ER diagram

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

Sorry, I am now sure what I am asking for, but anyway, if anyone may have or know the way of doing it.

I am new in Odoo. I want Odoo 8 database tables ER diagram. I know there are about 600 tables for Odoo. But I do not know how to get the ER diagram?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can use pgmodeler. https://pgmodeler.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free Odoo module, [Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) Maker](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/erd_maker/), which is currently available for versions 8, 9, & 10. It's relatively basic as far as the information provided, but it is easy to install and use.

If you need something more robust, then I would suggest installing and using [schemaspy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/). You can see some usage info on [this related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237736/3330552). This has a bit more setup involved and it takes longer to run (1-2 hours for as large/complicated as Odoo's database structure is), but it is able to produce *extremely detailed* diagrams and results in a great browse-able, local website with about all the information you could want.

Answer (score -1):

You can find here the ERD for Odoo12
https://soft-builder.com/odoo-data-model-by-erbuilder/